# Cannot open any website through IIS or locally

Tags: iis, iis-7

I am using IIS 7 and after trying several attempts such as:

- Doing iisreset through CMD
- Pinging the localhost (success!)
- Re-installing IIS Manager

I cannot open up any Sites. Whenever I try to browse through IIS (port 80) I am getting on IE 9: **Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage**.

Site was running fine like a week ago and I never installed anything else which could block port 80. Dont know what is going on. Can someone help! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Gunda, is it possible that the site has simply been Stopped?  Check the site in IIS and try Restart.  If all else fails you can install Wireshark (free), and it will help you troubleshoot where things are traveling around.

Good luck!